# Store and retrieve Gallery Image on Android

Tags: android, firebase, gallery, picasso, firebase-storage

I am creating a simple Android App which lets the user choose an Image from Gallery.

I use Picasso to load the Image from within onActivityResult and It works just fine using `data.getData();`

But if I open another Fragment and then I return back to this it doesn't load the chosen image.

I've tried to put the filePath into a File, as you can see now It's converted to a String but nothing happens. The Log says that the String contains something like this:

> /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170517_120403.jpg

Here is the code:

> Fragment

```html
package com.garro.vanderbiltchatapp.Fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawable;
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.garro.vanderbiltchatapp.R;
import com.garro.vanderbiltchatapp.Utils.ImageFilePath;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

/**
 * Created by garro on 16/05/2017.
 */

public class FragmentPresentation extends Fragment {

    private static final int SELECT_IMAGE = 102 ;
    private static final String TAG = "FragmentPresentation";
    private ImageView smallImageView, largeImageView;
    private TextView userTextView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private FirebaseUser user;

    String selectedImagePath;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_presentation, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.title_presentation);

        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        smallImageView = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.smallImageViewPresentation);
        largeImageView = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.largeImageViewPresentation);
        userTextView = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userTextView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        // Here I try to reload the Image but nothing happens
        try{
            if(!selectedImagePath.equals("")){
                Picasso
                        .with(getActivity())
                        .load(selectedImagePath)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                        .into(largeImageView);
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        largeImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.select_picture)),SELECT_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        if (user != null) {
            // Here we set the userLabel to the current user email
            userTextView.setText(user.getEmail());

            Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load(user.getPhotoUrl())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                    .error(R.drawable.logo)
                    .fit()
                    .centerInside()
                    .into(smallImageView, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            Bitmap imageBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)
                                    smallImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                            RoundedBitmapDrawable imageDrawable =
                                    RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), imageBitmap);
                            imageDrawable.setCircular(true);
                            imageDrawable.setCornerRadius(
                                    Math.max(imageBitmap.getWidth(),
                                            imageBitmap.getHeight()) / 2.0f);
                            smallImageView.setImageDrawable(imageDrawable);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {

                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE)
        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                if (data != null)
                {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    largeImageView.setClickable(false);
                    Picasso
                            .with(getActivity())
                            .load(data.getData())
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                            .into(largeImageView, new Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    largeImageView.setClickable(true);

                                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                                    //MEDIA GALLERY
                                    selectedImagePath = ImageFilePath.getPath(getActivity(), selectedImageUri);
                                    Log.i(TAG, ""+selectedImagePath);

                                    // I will do nothing with this but
                                    // it's only to show how to get the right Path from
                                    // gallery
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError() {

                                }
                            });
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> ImageFilePath.java

```html
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

/**
 * Created by garro on 17/05/2017.
 */

public class ImageFilePath {

    /**
     * Method for return file path of Gallery image
     *
     * @param context
     * @param uri
     * @return path of the selected image file from gallery
     */
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri)
    {

        // DocumentProvider
        if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri The Uri to query.
     * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```

> Fragment Layout

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/largeImageViewPresentation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/smallImageViewPresentation"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/largeImageViewPresentation"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="top|left" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/largeImageViewPresentation"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/User"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Why doesn't It reload the Image when I re-Create the Fragment or after the App gets Stopped??

This app uses FirebaseDatabase, if it could be useful to store the Image in FirebaseStorage and retrieve it, I'd do It. But how could I do?

Show me the best solution, please.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Start by getting rid of `ImageFilePath`. It will not work for most `Uri` values, and there is no requirement that it will work for anything that you get back from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. A `Uri` does not have to point to a file that you can access via the filesystem. If you want to have long-term access to the content, use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream`, then copy the bytes to a file that you control.

Comment: Can you please write me some code to make an example? Thanks

Comment: `getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData())` to get an `InputStream` on the `Uri` delivered to `onActivityResult()`.